# Which rule disprefers qualification conversions during reference binding?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider

```
void foo(int*& r);              // (1)
void foo(const int* const& r);  // (2)

int main() {
    int* p;
    foo(p);
}
```

[This calls (1) in all implementations I tested](https://godbolt.org/z/7r5zz57bf) but I can't figure out what in the C++ standard requires this result.

[[over.ics.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#1) implies that both reference bindings rank as identity conversions. `int*&` binds directly to an lvalue of type `int*` (obviously), and `const int* const&` also binds directly to an lvalue of type `int*`. (It doesn't convert the `int*` to a temporary `const int*` and bind to the temporary.)

Since both implicit conversion sequences are identity conversions, the overload resolution will be ambiguous unless there is a tie-breaker rule that distinguishes them.

[[over.ics.rank]/3.2.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.5) might be the tie-breaker intended to apply to this situation:

> `S1` and `S2` differ only in their qualification conversion ([conv.qual]) and yield similar types `T1` and `T2`, respectively, where `T1` can be converted to `T2` by a qualification conversion.

However, it's not clear that it actually applies. There is not actually a qualification conversion in (2); the reference simply binds to the `int*` *as if* it were a `const int*`. Also, `S1` and `S2` yield reference types, and [similarity does not apply to reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#2) (though I guess the definition still implies that a reference type is similar to itself).

Tie-breaker [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.6) doesn't apply; one of its conditions is "the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers"; but `const int*` and `int*` differ in a non-top-level cv-qualifier.

I don't see any other tie-breaker rule that is remotely relevant. Did I miss something that implies that (1) is better than (2)?

The issue description of [CWG1374](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1374) seems to allude to [over.ics.rank]/3.2.5 being relevant, so perhaps the issue is simply that that bullet's wording needs to be improved.

Comment: Before [CWG 2352](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2352.html) the second `r` wouldn't bind directly to `p` and there would be a difference in qualification conversion, so that the first overload would be chosen. This might have been an oversight in resolving that issue?

Comment: @user17732522 That seems correct to me. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user17732522 pointed out, the lack of a rule was an oversight while resolving [CWG2352](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2352.html).

I raised this with CWG, and it was agreed that there was an oversight. The result is [CWG2803](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2803.html), which adds the missing wording.